# Check if a line already exists in a file with JavaScript (Electron/node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, electron, metadata

I try to read the metadata of all files in a directory and save it and the file path to a file line by line. This works.

But now in my `toTXT()` function, I would like to check if a line already exists in the file. But I don't know how to do it.

I work with Electron / node.js

```js
var    fs = require('fs'),
 jDataView = require('jdataview');

function filelist(directory){
 return fs.readdirSync(directory);
}
function trimNullChars(str){
 return str.replace(/\0/g,'')
}
function readID3(file){

 var text = fs.readFileSync(file,'utf8');
 //console.log(text)

 var reader = new FileReader,
     dv = new jDataView(text);

 if (dv.getString(3, dv.byteLength - 128) == 'TAG') {
  var title  = dv.getString( 30, dv.tell() ),
    artist = dv.getString( 30, dv.tell() ),
    album  = dv.getString( 30, dv.tell() ),
    year   = dv.getString(  4, dv.tell() );
 }

 var metadata = {
   artist : trimNullChars(artist) ,
    album : trimNullChars(album)  ,
   year : trimNullChars(year)  ,
   title : trimNullChars(title)
 }

 return metadata

}
function toTXT(filename,data){

 if( !isStr(data) ){
  data = JSON.stringify(data);
 }

 // SAVE STRING
 fs.appendFile( filename, data + ',\n', function(error){ if(error){console.log(error)} });
}
function crawlFiles(path){
 var files = filelist(path);

 var filepaths = [];

 files.forEach( (file) => {
  var fullname = '' + path + '/' + file + '';
  filepaths.push(fullname);
 });

 filepaths.forEach( fp => {
  var obj = readID3(fp);
  obj.filepath = fp;
  toTXT( './db2.js', obj );
 });

}
```

Comment: do you want it to be ignored if it already exists?

Comment: To check if a line already exists in a file you'll need to re-read the file in its current state. Depending how big it is you could load it all into memory with something like readFileSync and then analyze the string, but if it is too big to load into memory you'd need to process it line by line using readline or streams. Have you considered memoizing data before it is written and checking that local data structure?

Comment: @etarrowo You don't need to do all that. A simple Set Object will allow you to check it on the first iteration.

Comment: @zfrisch Yes if it already exists it should be ignored.

Comment: @zfrisch yes memoizing using an object is probably best here, but in case thats not possible the postprocessing stuff would be necessary

Answer (score 0):

Use a cache to keep a list of what's been stored. The steps are simple:

- Create a Cache using a `Set` Object
- Stringify the data before sending it to the `toTXT` function.
- Check if the stringified data exists in the cache

  - if it doesn't, add the data
  - if it does, do nothing.

---

Code:

```
function crawlFiles( path ) {
    var files = filelist( path );
    var filepaths = [];

    var cache = new Set();

    files.forEach( ( file ) => {
        var fullname = '' + path + '/' + file + '';
        filepaths.push( fullname );
    } );
    filepaths.forEach( fp => {
        var obj = readID3( fp );
        obj.filepath = fp;

        var data = JSON.stringify( obj );
        if ( !cache.has( data ) ) {
            cache.add( data );
            toTXT( './db2.js', obj );
        }

    } );
}
```

---

### Aside:

Instead of reading/stringifying each file line by line and then writing it line by line, I would suggest stringifying all the data into a `Set` object ( which doesn't allow duplicates ), and then dumping it all at once into the file. This saves you processing and code.